# periodicTimeObserver for duration countdown in AVPlayer with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, cmtime

I have a time observer for AVPlayer that works great.  Im trying to get it to countdown from the duration of the audio 0.

It works and does count down now I'm just having some trouble with formatting.

if you see the picture below you'll see what i mean.  It goes from whole minutes:seconds 3:00, to weird numbers 3:-1 ect.

[image]
[image]

any ideas what I've done wrong?

heres the code for the timer:

```
let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 1)
self.audioPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (progressTime) in

let secondsProgress = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)

    let secondsStringProgress = String(format: "%02d", Int((secondsProgress.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))))
    let minuitesStringProgress = String(format: "%02d", Int(secondsProgress) / 60)
    //self.countDownLabel.text = "\(minuitesStringProgress):\(secondsStringProgress)"

    if let duration = self.audioPlayer?.currentItem!.asset.duration {

        let secondsDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

            let secondsStringDuration = String(format: "%02d", Int((secondsDuration.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))))
            let minuitesStringDuration = String(format: "%02d", Int(secondsDuration) / 60)

                let secondsString = String(format: "%02d", Int(secondsStringDuration)! - Int(secondsStringProgress)!)
                let minuitesString = String(format: "%02d", Int(minuitesStringDuration)! - Int(minuitesStringProgress)!)

            self.countDownLabel.isHidden = false
            self.countDownLabel.text = "\(minuitesString):\(secondsString)"

        self.horizontalSlider.value = Float(secondsProgress / secondsDuration)
        self.circleSlider.value = Float(secondsProgress / secondsDuration)

    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this function to display formatted date

```
  func getFormatedTime(FromTime timeDuration:Int) -> String {

    let minutes = Int(timeDuration) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(timeDuration) % 60
    let strDuration = String(format:"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    return strDuration
  }
```

use like this

```
        let strDuration = self.getFormatedTime(FromTime: recordingDuration)
```

or directly like this in `addPeriodicTimeObserver` method

```
      recordingDuration = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.playerItem?.asset.duration)!))-Float(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.playerItem?.currentTime())!))
```

pass it to  `getFormatedTime` set text of return value

just two lines of code

Comment: That is a very nice clean way of achieving this.  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: As a side not, this has smoothed out my scrubbing also.  double win!

Comment: @Pippo Thanks  and happy coding